# Dataloader Command line error

Tags: data-loader, data, commandline

I need to be able to run Data Loader from the command line (we need a scheduled import/export of data once per day). I created the conf file but get the error message below when I run the proccess.bat file.

It appears that encryption tool is creating an encrypted password with a control character that cannot be put in the XML conf file? Is there any way around this, or will I need to change the password? Can I maybe change the key and re-encrypt and get a different encrypted value?

The char at the location in the error message, in Notepad, looks like two "squished" square brackets together, but it can't be copied and pasted (shows up as the black triangle question mark) so I assume it is indeed a char that can't be used in XML?

**org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 15 in XML document from file [C:\path to file\process-conf.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 15; columnNumber: 62; An invalid XML character (Unicode: 0x1a) was found in the value of attribute "value" and element is "entry".**

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. You cannot do anything with the char I mentioned, so I generated a new key file and re-encrypted. This caused another error because my original plain text password had a special char "^" that doesn't work with the encrypt process.

It won't give an error but if you encrypt then decrypt you will see the char is eliminated.